# Is there a default path to library in ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, compilation

folks!

I'm using `ubuntu 12.04` and trying to compile a `boost` test program. I installed boost with

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

an so, I don't know where i can find my libraries. I tried do compile that using

```
g++ -lboost_system -lboost_thread boost_test.cpp
```

thinking maybe to have some default path where ubuntu installed boost automatically, but it was wrong and I had the following:

> /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In function
>   `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to`
>   boost::system::generic_category()' boost_test.cpp:(.text+0xd8):
>   undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to`
>   boost::system::system_category()' /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In function
>   `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17):
>   undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
>   /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In function
>   `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[_ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv]+0x5):
>   undefined reference to`boost::system::system_category()'
>   /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In function
>   `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj[_ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj]+0x19):
>   undefined reference to`pthread_key_create' /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In
>   function
>   `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service,
>   boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::thread_info>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceENS4_11thread_infoEE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceENS4_11thread_infoEE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to`pthread_key_delete' /tmp/ccTKXzTR.o: In
>   function
>   `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl,
>   unsigned char>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
>   boost_test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEhE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEhE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15):
>   undefined reference to`pthread_key_delete' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Can someone help-me to figure out if my library is correctly installed and compile that?

Comment: A duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7765498/1011154), the accepted answer there should resolve your problem

Comment: Thanks, man, it was exactly what i was searching.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 5):

I found out `/usr/include/boost` is the path to boost headers and `/usr/lib` contains all boost libraries i want to.